# How to @Inject data class with constructor in dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have this Response Object from API

```
data class ReqSpaceAvailability @Inject constructor(var stationFrom: String? = null,
                                                    var stationTo: String? = null,
                                                    var detailNumPlaces: String? = "1",
                                                    var detailTypePlaces: String? = "0",
                                                    var direction: ArrayList<ObjDirection>? = null)
```

But it's not compiling saying

> "error: Types may only contain one @Inject constructor."

Comment: hi i am having this error, have you found the solution? Is it possible to inject multiple constructor in dagger?